# Open_basedir error out of the blue

Tags: php-errors

I recently started getting errors in the control panel on a site that has not been touched in a while.

Message: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/hosting/webs/mysite/mysite.com/web/themes/) is not within the allowed path(s)

Filename: libraries/Core.php

Any idea what could have caused the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked with the hosting company? They may have updated the server software recently and enabled `open_basedir`.

P.S. You shouldn't post your real server paths publicly, it's a security concern.

Comment: I'm having the client check with their hosting company. I've edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: Note that people still can see the original post at this url: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/posts/21390/revisions

Answer (score 0):

It ended up just being a path issue. When they moved the install, they didn't update some of the paths to the new server path.